# Implementing Stack using 2 Queues

Tags: c++, c, stack, queue

Why does this code work:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

#define N n *
#define Q q *
#define S s *

typedef struct n
{
    int data;
    struct N nxt;
}n;

typedef struct q
{
    N f;
    N r;
}q;

typedef struct stack
{
    Q q1;
    Q q2;
}s;
Q Createq()
{
    Q qq = (Q)malloc(sizeof(q));
    qq->f = qq->r  = 0;
    return qq;
}

S CreateStk()
{
    S stk = (S)malloc(sizeof(s));
    stk->q1 = Createq();
    stk->q2 = Createq();
    return stk;
}

int Deq(Q qq)
{
    if(qq->f == 0 && qq->r == 0) return -1;
    N nn = qq->r;
    int data = nn->data;
    qq->r = qq->r->nxt;
    free(nn);
    if(!qq->r)
        qq->f = 0;
    return data;
}

void Enq(Q qq, int data)
{
    if(!qq->f)
    {
        N nn = (N)malloc(sizeof(n));
        nn->data = data;
        nn->nxt = 0;
        qq->f = qq->r = nn;
    }
    else
    {
        N nn = (N)malloc(sizeof(n));
        nn->data = data;
        nn->nxt = 0;
        qq->f->nxt = nn;
        qq->f = nn;
    }
}

void Push(S stk, int data)
{
    Enq(stk->q2,data);

    while(stk->q1->f)
    {
        Enq(stk->q2,Deq(stk->q1));
    }

    Q t = stk->q1;
    stk->q1 = stk->q2;
    stk->q2 = t;
}

int Pop(S stk)
{
    return Deq(stk->q1);
}
int main() 
{
    S stk = CreateStk();
    Push(stk,10);
    Push(stk,30);
    Push(stk,40);
    Push(stk,50);
    printf("\nPopped: %d.", Pop(stk));
    printf("\nPopped: %d.", Pop(stk));
    printf("\nPopped: %d.", Pop(stk));
    printf("\nPopped: %d.", Pop(stk));
    return 0;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> ```
> Popped: 50.
> Popped: 40.
> Popped: 30.
> Popped: 10.
> ```

While this does not:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

#define N n *
#define Q q *

typedef struct n
{
    int data;
    struct N nxt;
}n;

typedef struct q
{
    N f;
    N r;
}q;

Q Createq()
{
    Q qq = (Q)malloc(sizeof(q));
    qq->f = qq->r  = 0;
    return qq;
}

int Deq(Q qq)
{
    if(qq->f == 0 && qq->r == 0) return -1;
    N nn = qq->r;
    int data = nn->data;
    qq->r = qq->r->nxt;
    free(nn);
    if(!qq->r)
        qq->f = 0;
    return data;
}

void Enq(Q qq, int data)
{
    if(!qq->f)
    {
        N nn = (N)malloc(sizeof(n));
        nn->data = data;
        nn->nxt = 0;
        qq->f = qq->r = nn;
    }
    else
    {
        N nn = (N)malloc(sizeof(n));
        nn->data = data;
        nn->nxt = 0;
        qq->f->nxt = nn;
        qq->f = nn;
    }
}

void Push(Q qq1, Q qq2, int data)
{
    Enq(qq2,data);

    while(qq1->f)
    {
        Enq(qq2,Deq(qq1));
    }

    Q t = qq1;
    qq1 = qq2;
    qq2 = t;
}

int Pop(Q qq1)
{
    return Deq(qq1);
}

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    Q qq1 = Createq();
    Q qq2 = Createq();
    Push(qq1,qq2,10);
    Push(qq1,qq2,30);
    Push(qq1,qq2,40);
    Push(qq1,qq2,50);
    printf("\nPopped: %d.", Pop(qq1));
    printf("\nPopped: %d.", Pop(qq1));
    printf("\nPopped: %d.", Pop(qq1));
    printf("\nPopped: %d.", Pop(qq1));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> Popped: -1.
>      Popped: -1.
>      Popped: -1.
>      Popped: -1.

The expected output is the first one as its obvious by the question heading. However i do not understand the gory details of why the code did not work when i did not encapsulate the 2 queues in a struct in my second example.

PS: I think the problem is with the `Push` method - but not sure what went wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from being horrendously hard to read, the problem is that your second `Push` function changes the values of its parameters in the following lines of code.

```
Q t = qq1;
qq1 = qq2;
qq2 = t;
```

`qq1` and `qq2` are parameters of the function, so the new values are not updated in the calling function (`main`).

One way to fix this is to make the parameters pass by reference:

```
void Push(Q &qq1, Q &qq2, int data)
```

That way, changes to `qq1` and `qq2` will also change the values in the calling function.

Comment: Upticked. And that code isn't just horrendous to read. You can lose the "to read" and it is even more accurate. If one were trying to muster a *less-efficient* way of implementing a stack, one would be hard pressed to beat this algorithm.

Comment: The Dark : Sorry about the readability part.
@WhozCraig : It was never about efficiency, where in my question i asked anything about efficiency? It was just a puzzle i was trying to solve. Sometimes unneeded expert advice is as useless as such puzzles.

Comment: @The Dark: +1. In addition, don't you think that packing the queue in a struct is actually better here than passing reference or double pointer even? Your answer explains what went wrong but i would go with OP's first way of coding here.

Comment: @al-Acme I agree, the first way encapsulates the code better and makes it easier to call.

Comment: the code should always check the returned value from a call to malloc() to assure the operation was successful